# Why content does not fit into UIWebView?

Tags: swift, webview, uiwebview, zooming

Is "scalesPageToFit" working as it should work? As you see from the first print screen: in the up-left corner you don't see the loupe (it is cutted). Instead, in the second image, the loupe is there and the content is shown as I would like it to be shown... shouldn't be this the "scalesPageToFit"?

My situation is the one you see in the first picture and here is what I've done:

```
var url = NSURL(string: urlToLoad)
var request = NSURLRequest(URL:url!) // or NSMutableURL ??
webView.loadRequest(request)

webView.scalesPageToFit = true
```

So: is "scalesPageToFit" not working as it should? Or it is working but its function is not to do what I need?

Thank you!

[image]

[image]

Comment: Check your webview frame and paste here with question.

Comment: @Mrunal what do you mean with "webview frame" sorry??

Comment: NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromCGRect(self.yourWebViewName.frame));

Comment: @Mrunal Here it is [3673:517922] {{0, 20}, {600, 600}}

:)

Comment: Try this: do not load any url and assign different background color to webview (red, yellow, anything) and check then. Because frame seems correct.